# Word for Mac 2011 Form/Templates - field size

Tags: templates, forms

I've made a form template for other users to complete.  It is a new employee record  form.  The size of each text box is unlimited, but if a person's name is lengthy, the text boxes on the rest of the line are moved and sometimes even go to the next line.  How can I prevent this from happening?  I've allowed plenty of room for lengthy entries before the next text box and I used tabs between each of the text boxes. But when the text I'm entering in a field goes beyond that next tab stop, everything moves to the right.   Thanks for any help you can provide.